# VHDL with-select and "AND"

Tags: vhdl

I wrote a code  and i got a problem defining the if statement

```
  port ( 
  clk: in std_logic;
  restb: in std_logic;
  bout : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
  );
  end entity;

  architecture behave of mod9and5 is 

  signal state: unsigned(3 downto 0);
  signal state_next: unsigned(3 downto 0);

  begin

  with state select state_next <=
  "0001" when (state <= "0000") and (mode = '0'); 


  "0000" when others;
```

-- here is my problem
-- what I wanted to do is if input 0000 AND the mode 0 then 0001

Comment: Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at HW31911.vhd(24) near text ",";  expecting "<="

Comment: I already have mode : in std.... and also fixed bout : out...

Comment: with state select state_next <=
"0001" when "0000",
"0010" when "0001" & (mode = '0');
"0011" when "0010" & (mode = '0'),
"0100" when "0011" & (mode = '0'),
"0101" when "0100" & (mode = '0'),
"0110" when "0101" & (mode = '1'),
"0111" when "0110" & (mode = '1'),
"1000" when "0111" & (mode = '1'),
"1001" when "1000" & (mode = '1'),

Comment: This is not proper code. Please give us a [minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

`with.. select` is not an if-statement. But anyhow. Google it! [vhdl with select](http://insights.sigasi.com/tech/signal-assignments-vhdl-withselect-whenelse-and-case.html)

The symbol `;` ends a statement. It is in the wrong place.

As you are using two inputs for selecting, you will have to concatenate them before using select.
Thus:

```
    signal select_input : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
begin
    select_input <= state & mode;
    with select_input select state_next <=
        "0001" when "00000",
        "0010" when "00010",
        "0011" when "00100",
        "0100" when "00110",
        "0101" when "01000",
        "0110" when "01011",
        "0111" when "01101",
        "1000" when "01111",
        "1001" when "10001",
        "0000" when others; -- required!
```